# How do i find inverse of this function?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I need to find $f^{-1} $ of $f(x)= -x|x|/(1+x^2)$

I divided function into parts x>0 and x<0.

For $ x>0 $, $f(x)= -x^2/(1+x^2)$

Replace x with y and after solving the quadratic i get $y=-\sqrt{-x/(x+1)}$ , which makes it *undefined*.

For $ x<0 $, $f(x)= x^2/(1+x^2)$

Replace x with y and after solving the quadratic i get $y=\sqrt{x/(-x+1)}$.

The correct answer given in my book is  $y=sig(-x)\sqrt{|x|/(-|x|+1)}$.

Can anybody point out my error ?

Comment: When you solve a quadratic, you should get two answers

Comment: You said $x<0$ and replace $x$ with $y$, but $\sqrt{x/(1-x)}>0$

Comment: Yes so for  x>0  and x<0  i am getting 4 total answers out of which i need to reject two.

Comment: I think you're getting confused because you switched $x$ with $y$, and they have opposite signs.  Just say, for $x>0$, $y<0$ and $x=\sqrt{-y/(y+1)}$, which makes sense

Comment: or for $x>0$, $y<0$, and then, when you switch $y$ with $x$, $y=\sqrt{-x/(x+1)}$ is defined

Comment: How did you decide x>0 $y=\sqrt{-x/(x+1)}$. And not $y=-\sqrt{-x/(x+1)}$? Also i don't see how is it defined? If i substitute  x=1 i get y = sqrt(-1/2), which is not defined.

Comment: I solved it before switching $x$ and $y$ to get $x=\sqrt{-y/(y+1)}$ for $x>0$.  In that case, $y<0$ before the switch.  After the switch, $x<0$, so this case doesn't cover $x=1$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\sign}{\text{sign}}$
Since $\;y=\cfrac{-x|x|}{1+x^2}\;,\;$ it results that $\;\color{blue}{\sign(x)=\sign(-y)}\;.$

Moreover,

$|y|=\cfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}\;,$

$\left(1-|y|\right)x^2=|y|\;,$

$x=\color{blue}{\sign(x)}\sqrt{\cfrac{|y|}{1-|y|}}\;,$

$x=\color{blue}{\sign(-y)}\sqrt{\cfrac{|y|}{1-|y|}}\;.$

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused, because $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs, and then you switched them.

For $x>0$, $y<0$, so the solution would be $x=\sqrt{-y/(y+1})$, which makes sense with the signs,

and then you could switch $x$ and $y$ to get $y=\sqrt{-x/(x+1)}$,

keeping in mind that, after the switch, $y>0$ and $x<0$;

that agrees with the answer in your book for $x<0$.